# Why does my sqlite update request does not work?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to split all the entry of the database that has a '/' into 2 or more row, I managed to insert the 2nd and more word into new row but I can't edit the original row to delete these word and keep only the first word.

```js
async function mutator(id, french, pierrick){
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject){
        const sql = "UPDATE dictionnaire SET francais = ?, pierrick = ? WHERE id = ?";
        db.run(sql, [french, pierrick, id], (err, row) => {
            if (err){ console.log(err); reject(err);}
            else resolve(row); 
        });
    });
}

                if (!(row.francais == null) && row.francais.search("/") != 0 ){
                    let synonyms = row.francais.split("/")
                    await mutator(row.id, synonyms[0], row.pierrick);
                    for (let i = 1; i < synonyms.length; i++){
                        await setter(row, synonyms[i], row.pierrick);
                    }
                }
```

I'm not getting any error, and i don't have any modification in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little edit

```js
async function mutator(args, french, pierrick) {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    const sql = "UPDATE dictionnaire SET francais = ?, pierrick = ? WHERE id = ?";
    db.run(sql, [french, pierrick, args.id], (err, row) => {
      if (err){ console.log(err); reject(err);}
      else resolve(row); 
    });
  });
}

if (!(row.francais == null) && row.francais.search("/") != 0 ) {
  let synonyms = row.francais.split("/")
  await mutator(row, synonyms[0], row.pierrick);
  for (let i = 1; i < synonyms.length; i++) {
    await setter(row, synonyms[i], row.pierrick);
  }
}
```

It should do exactly the same thing but it works, I don't understand why, but it do

Comment: So the reason it works is that in the mutator function on the third line, you refer to `args.id` to fulfill the `id` arg of the query. This means you expect an object with an id property to be passed to the first parameter of that function.
However when they called `await mutator(...` they passed row.id and not row. so therefore he passed the property of the object (a string or number) and not the entire thing. So it would try to ask a number for it's id which is invalid.